# Intellisense for master pages stopped working in Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, master-pages, intellisense

I have a site which hosted on a shared server. Today during my coding my conputer got blue screen (still have xp =]), so when it got back I started my VS08. After I reconnect to the server it told me that the server has new version of a file and if I want to copy it to my computer. Because I familiar with this problem I knew this not gonna be the only message, so to prevent it from popping again I went to Documents and Settings[user]\Local Settings\Temp and delete VWDWebCache folder. after that I continued with VS.

And ever since I cant get intellisense with Master pages, I mean if I do Master. I dont see the master page functions, and before that it worked.. All the rest (classes,dlls etc..) was not showed ok, but rebuild web site fixed that..

Any Ideas?

P.S. I tried the [text editor-all languages-Statement](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2007/12/01/intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) completion thing..

Thanks.

**Solution:**
The problem fixed itself.
In my opinion I just needed to give VS a little time (lets say half an hour - hour) to be open in this projects, and stuff will be download automatically. Although its not happened right a way..

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would go is run through some of the visual Studio switches, like

```
 devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs
```

You can search the documentation to determine which you think you need to try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=VS.80).aspx

If this does not yield a win, most likely the Intellisense file is corrupt. This will either mean finding the file on a non-corrupt system or running a fix "install" of Visual Studio.